# In microsoft bot framework SDK V3 welcome message gets triggered twice

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework

I have a bot where the root dialog is a choice prompt(yes/no) which I want to show the user when the bot starts. Below are the code snippets for conversationUpdate and the root dialog. The issue here is when the user clicks yes or no in the root dialog i.e welcome message, the root dialog is triggered second time and it again asks the user to click yes or no. After that the bot is continuing its normal flow but I want the root dialog to trigger only once.

Thanks in Advance

```
bot.on('conversationUpdate', function (message) {
if (message.membersAdded && message.membersAdded.length > 0) {
        message.membersAdded.forEach(function (identity) {
        if (identity.id === message.address.bot.id) {
            bot.beginDialog(message.address, '/');
        }
    });
} 
});
```

Root Dialog code:

```
bot.dialog('/', [
    function (session) {
    builder.Prompts.choice(session,"some text", ["yes", "no"], { listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button });
},
function (session, results) {
    if (results.response.entity == "yes"){
        session.send("some text");
    }
    else if (results.response.entity == "no"){
        session.send("some text");
    }

    session.beginDialog('/nextDialog');
}
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4387

Comment: Thanks @Zhao. I followed the thread you have shared and they mentioned an workaround in this link [https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4245](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4245). I used that workaround any my bot is working as expected.